# Getting error when I do redirect in a client component in Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, next-auth

In my root page.js of my project, I'm checking the role of the current logged user and redirecting to one specific page.

This is my code:

```
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default async function Home() {
   const { data: session, status } = useSession();

   console.log(session);

   /* This is what I get when I console.log the sesion object;
   
   {
      "user": {
          "name": "Admin",
          "email": "admin@mywebsite.com"
      },
      "expires": "2023-10-15T06:34:54.844Z",
      "access_token": "myAccessToken",
      "id_token": "myIdToken",
      "roles": [
          "admin",
      ]
  }*/

   if (session?.roles?.includes("comunidad")) {
      redirect('/client');
   }

   if (session?.roles?.includes("admin")) {
      redirect('/admin');
   }

   if (session?.roles?.includes("consejo")) {
      redirect('/consejo');
   }

   return <></>;
}
```

This redirect works properly, but the problem is that when I get the new page, I get the following error about react context (line 7):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/
    at ...
```

And:

```
The above error occurred in the <Home> component:

    at Home
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/
    at ...

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, RedirectErrorBoundary.
```

I understand that the context error I am having is due to the fact that I am accessing a React context before it has been initialized. But how can I fix this?

I tried to check if `session` is null before to redirect, but I get the same context error:

```
   if (session) {
      if (session?.roles?.includes("comunidad")) {
         redirect('/client');
      }

      if (session?.roles?.includes("admin")) {
         redirect('/admin');
      }

      if (session?.roles?.includes("consejo")) {
         redirect('/consejo');
      }
   }
```

I have no idea how to fix this